# Hyperbolic distance between two coordinates

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

> Find the hyperbolic distances between the following pairs of points
>
> ( 4/3, 0,5/3) , (3/4, 0,5/4) ∈ H^+
>
> where H^+ = {x,y,z ∈ R^3 | z^2-y^2-x^2=1 and z>0}

Own work:

The formula I have been given is

d(w,z) = ln({1 + |(w-z)/(1-($\bar w$z)|}/{1-|(w-z)/(1-($\bar w$z)|})

where d(w,z) is the distance between to complex numbers w and z.

Im struggling on how to use this formula when I have been given coordinates rather than two complex numbers.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may map $(x,y,z)$ in your hyperboloid representation to the complex unit disk (Poincaré disk) by 
$$ \left(x,y,z=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\right) \mapsto \frac{ x + i y}{1+z}$$
You should then calculate (through the formula you state) the distance in the Poincaré disk. You may google on "Poincaré disk model" to get further information.

Comment: Thank you this really helped

Comment: Given that you use the hyperboloid coordinates, but the Poincaré metric, I wouldn't know of any other way. But your two points correspond to simple nice (real-valued) points in the unit disk: $1/2$ and $1/3$ so very easy to calculate their distance.

Comment: are the hyoerboloid coordinates the ones provided in the question?

Comment: Yes, you may have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model (around two thirds down the page: Relation to the hyperboloid model)